# Shuffling xml output before echoing

Tags: php, xml, shuffle

I have a script that grabs an xml of my database generated by php and I would like to shuffle the rows before the php script echos the xml so that each time i access the database xml file, I'll receive the database in a different order.

here's part of my php script that outputs the xml:

```
$dom =  new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("database");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: text/xml");


while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
    $node = dom->createElement("data");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

    $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("date", $row['date']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("latitude", $row['latitude']);
    $newnode->setattribute("longitude", $row['longitude']);

}
```

This is where I'd like to randomize the xml output if possible.  This seems like the most logical place, but if there's a better place, that's fine with me.

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Here's a sample of my xml:

```
<database>
  <data id="1" name="blah" date="2012-10-10" latitude="0" longitude="0"/>
  <data id="3" name="blah" date="2012-10-10" latitude="0" longitude="0"/>
  <data id="4" name="blah" date="2012-10-10" latitude="0" longitude="0"/>
</database>
```

Simply put, I would like the xml rows to be in a different order each time i access it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this problem is to use a temporary array to store the rows fetched from DB, then shuffle this array, then walk through it:

```
$records = array();
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $records[] = $row;
}

shuffle($records);

foreach ($records as $row) {
    $node = dom->createElement("data");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

    $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
    ...
}
```

The other way is use the original array as it is, but randomize the insertion process instead:

```
$prevnode = null;
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $node = dom->createElement("data");
    if ($prevnode && rand(0, 1) === 0) {
      $newnode = $prevnode->insertBefore($node);
    } else {
      $newnode  = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    }
    $prevnode = $newnode;

    $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your result set is not very large and your database supports it, you can have the database shuffle the results for you. For example, MySQL can do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY rand();
```

Your database may differ.

You could also separate XML generation from result collection. Shuffle the intermediate array:

```php
function get_database_results($dbconn=null) {
    $rows = false;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM database';
    $res = mysql_query($query, $dbconn);
    if ($res) {
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $rows;
}

function array_to_sxe($rows) {
    $sxe = simplexml_load_string('<database></database>');
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data = $sxe->addChild('data');
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $data->addAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $sxe;
}

$rows = get_database_results();
shuffle($rows);
$sxe = array_to_sxe($rows);
header('Content-Type: application/xml'); // NOT text/xml!
echo $sxe->asXML();
```

I will now rant about **encodings**.

You have to be more careful about your encodings! As it is, you can very easily generate malformed XML.

- `text/xml` means that the xml is in 7-bit ascii. That is very unlikely what you meant.
- `application/xml` means that the xml is utf-8. This is what `DOMDocument` and `SimpleXML` output by default, and *only accept utf-8 values for methods like `setAttribute`*! This means you need to be *absolutely sure*:

  1. That the strings you put into the database are utf-8.
  2. That the connection between php and the database is utf-8. (Using `SET NAMES utf8` or the `charset` parameter to the DSN with PDO--which you should be using instead of `mysql_*`)
  3. That the strings you pull out of the database are utf-8, or at least are converted to utf-8 before use.

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
ORDER BY rand()
```

to your SQL-Query

Comment: Please let me know what's wrong about doing this way... or remove your downvote